# Parsing webpage that is all text

Tags: python, text, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to parse webpage that is a plain text document, it's encoded in HTML so I tried using BeautifulSoup to pull out the text and make a list, but I wasn't able to.

```
<body>
    <pre>
    --------------------
    BDMEP - INMET
    --------------------
    Estação           : PONTA PORA - MS (OMM: 83702)
    Latitude  (graus) : -22.55
    Longitude (graus) : -55.71
    Altitude  (metros): 650.00
    Estação Operante
    Inicio de operação: 24/11/1941
    Periodo solicitado dos dados: 01/01/2015 a 17/11/2016
    Os dados listados abaixo são os que encontram-se digitados no BDMEP
    Hora em UTC
    --------------------
    Obs.: Os dados aparecem separados por ; (ponto e vírgula) no formato txt.
     Para o formato planilha XLS, 
    <a href="instrucao.html" target="_top" rel="facebox">siga as instruções</a>
    --------------------
Estacao;Data;Hora;Precipitacao;TempMaxima;TempMinima;Insolacao;Evaporacao Piche;Temp Comp Media;Umidade Relativa Media;Velocidade do Vento Media;
83702;01/01/2015;0000;;;;;;;73.5;3.333333;
83702;06/01/2016;1200;5;;;;;;;;
83702;07/01/2016;0000;;;;;;;76.25;2.40072;
83702;01/02/2016;1200;15.2;;;;;;;;
    </pre>    
</body>
```

I'm interested in:

```
    Piche;Temp Comp Media;Umidade Relativa Media;Velocidade do Vento Media;
    83702;01/01/2015;0000;;;;;;;73.5;3.333333;
    83702;06/01/2016;1200;5;;;;;;;;
    83702;07/01/2016;0000;;;;;;;76.25;2.40072;
    83702;01/02/2016;1200;15.2;;;;;;;;
```

Ideally to construct a DataFrame and save as a CSV.

So far I tried stuff like:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(a.content, 'html.parser')
soup = soup.find_all('pre')
text = []
for i in soup:
    print(i)
    text.append(i)
```

But it has not done the trick. It makes it all one entry in the list.

Comment: it is text so use standard `string` functions like `split('\n')`, or slicing `[start_row:end_row]`. BS is usefull only with HTML tags.

Comment: Ah, seems like I fired off in the wrong direction

Comment: `I'm trying to parse webpage that is a plain text document` So what you want is text-parsing tools. Parsing the text looks to be the bulk of this task. Very little, if any, is really HTML parsing. `bs4` is great for HTML parsing, but that's not really what this task is. @furas gave a great answer on this; be sure to accept it as an answer, if it was helpful to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`BS` is usefull for HTML tags but you have mostly text so use string functions like `split('\n')` and slicing `[start_row:end_row]`

your HTML text

```
content = '''<body>
    <pre>
    --------------------
    BDMEP - INMET
    --------------------
    Estação           : PONTA PORA - MS (OMM: 83702)
    Latitude  (graus) : -22.55
    Longitude (graus) : -55.71
    Altitude  (metros): 650.00
    Estação Operante
    Inicio de operação: 24/11/1941
    Periodo solicitado dos dados: 01/01/2015 a 17/11/2016
    Os dados listados abaixo são os que encontram-se digitados no BDMEP
    Hora em UTC
    --------------------
    Obs.: Os dados aparecem separados por ; (ponto e vírgula) no formato txt.
     Para o formato planilha XLS, 
    <a href="instrucao.html" target="_top" rel="facebox">siga as instruções</a>
    --------------------
Estacao;Data;Hora;Precipitacao;TempMaxima;TempMinima;Insolacao;Evaporacao Piche;Temp Comp Media;Umidade Relativa Media;Velocidade do Vento Media;
83702;01/01/2015;0000;;;;;;;73.5;3.333333;
83702;06/01/2016;1200;5;;;;;;;;
83702;07/01/2016;0000;;;;;;;76.25;2.40072;
83702;01/02/2016;1200;15.2;;;;;;;;
    </pre>    
</body>'''
```

and

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'html.parser')
text = soup.find('pre').text
lines = text.split('\n')
print(lines[-6:-1])
```

or in one line

```
print(content.split('\n')[-7:-2])
```

If table has more rows then you can search last `----------------` to find start of table

```
last = content.rfind('    --------------------')
lines = content[last:].split('\n')
print(lines[1:-2])
```

And now you can split lines into columns using `split(';')` to create data for pandas :)

Or use `io.StringIO` to create file-like object in memory and use `pd.read_csv()`

```
import pandas as pd
import io

last = content.rfind('    --------------------')

lines = content[last:].split('\n')[1:-2]

# create one string with table
text = '\n'.join(lines)

# create file-like object with text
fileobject = io.StringIO(text)

# use file-like object with read_csv()
df = pd.read_csv(fileobject, delimiter=';')

print(df)
```

or

```
import pandas as pd
import io

start = content.rfind('    --------------------')
start += len('    --------------------')
end   = content.rfind('    </pre>')

text = content[start:end]

fileobject = io.StringIO(text)

df = pd.read_csv(fileobject, delimiter=';')

print(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

you need re to do this job

in:

```
import re

re.findall(r'\w+;.+\n', string=html)
```

out:

```
['Estacao;Data;Hora;Precipitacao;TempMaxima;TempMinima;Insolacao;Evaporacao Piche;Temp Comp Media;Umidade Relativa Media;Velocidade do Vento Media;\n',
 '83702;01/01/2015;0000;;;;;;;73.5;3.333333;\n',
 '83702;06/01/2016;1200;5;;;;;;;;\n',
 '83702;07/01/2016;0000;;;;;;;76.25;2.40072;\n',
 '83702;01/02/2016;1200;15.2;;;;;;;;\n']
```